# CoreData update crashing on "deleteObject"

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

**EDIT: If anyone is having the same issue, index Path wasn't the problem.
The problem was that I wasn't sending the fetchedResultsController and the managedObjectContext from the Master view controller, (where my tableview was) to my detail view controller (where I was updating the data),
Therefore it was trying to delete data at a certain index, but it had no data.**

so I'm getting an error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-deleteObject: requires a non-nil argument'

But the thing is, it's not *nil*. This is the method:

```
- (void) updateMethod {

    // NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:self.indexToDelete];
    //NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.indexToDelete inSection:0];
    //NSLog(@"path = %@", indexPath);

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];

    [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:self.indexToDelete]];

    ContactDetails *contactDetails = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name]inManagedObjectContext:context];

    contactDetails.address = self.txtAddress.text;
    contactDetails.firstName = self.txtFirstName.text;
    contactDetails.lastName = self.txtLastName.text;
    contactDetails.image = self.txtPicture.text;

    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);

    }

}
```

This is the output of self.indexToDelete:

> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Are we supposed to know why your FRC doesn't have an entity at the given index path, really ?

Comment: what else should I include?

Comment: Complete logic related to `self.indexToDelete` and `FRC`, but that would be a too broad question. You need to narrow the problem first, trace the changes of `indexToDelete` and calls to `updateMethod` as well as the changes of your `FRC` request, you should be able to find inconsistency.

Comment: No problem, you should post an answer and let the question to remain being a question.

Comment: yeah Will Do, since I'm under 10 reputation I need to wait 8 hours before I can accept it as an answer lol.